# Append String to native Java array

Tags: java, arrays, string, append, native

Is there a more elegant way (preferably in the SDK) which will take an existing array of N String objects and append another String so that the array now has N+1 String objects? See below how I did it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringArrayAppend {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] selectionArgs={"3","2"};
    //Is there a SDK method to Arrays.append(selectionArgs,"1");?


    int newSize=selectionArgs.length+1;
    int indexNewElem=selectionArgs.length;
    String[] selectionArgs2=new String[newSize];
    System.arraycopy(selectionArgs, 0, selectionArgs2, 0, selectionArgs.length);
    selectionArgs2[indexNewElem]="1";
    selectionArgs=selectionArgs2;
    selectionArgs2=null;

    System.out.println("selectionArgs="+Arrays.toString(selectionArgs));


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in three lines, but the overall efficiency is going to be the same:

```
String[] a = new String[] {"quick", "brown", "fox"};

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
s.add("jumps");
a = s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2mv6I4)

However, the best approach when you need expandability of your container is to use an `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for. I did try it with asList(...) before but couldn't figure out how to get ride of the casting errors. Thanks!

Comment: But note that this actually does three copies of your array (whereas OP code had just one): in the ArrayList constructor, a second one when you add (because the capacity needs to be extended), and a third when you call toArray.

Answer (score 2):

If you stick with using Java Arrays I don't know of an elegant way to append one onto another, other than like you did (create another array with the correct size and simply add the new elements to the end of the array).

Edit: I found a one-liner solution using the Apache Commons Lang Library [ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

How about using an ArrayList? ArrayLists are dynamically sized and would allow you to simply add the elements (using ArrayList.add(Object o)).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the JDK, I am afraid.

You could pull in Commons Lang, or just make a helper method (like the one in your current code) yourself.

You can simplify the code a little by making use of [`Arrays#copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29) (which allows the copy to be one element longer than the original).

No matter how you do it, you will end up with a new array. Since arrays cannot be resized, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Didn't know that copyOf existed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, short of converting your array to/from a list, there's nothing in the JDK to make this operation easier. If you don't mind pulling in [Google's Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained), you can use its [`ObjectArrays.concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#concat(T[],%20T)) method.

Using the values from your example code, it would look like this:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {"3", "2"};
selectionArgs = ObjectArrays.concat(selectionArgs, "1");
```